# How to modify the design of textarea after sending a message in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a simple chat application and in the send message form I have a "growable" `textarea` and a submit `button`. The `textarea` is set firstly to a fixed height and once the message of the user begins to be longer than that height then the text area begins to be larger.That continues till the height of the grown `textarea` be 300px , then a scrollbar appears.

The problem is that when the user send a long message that led the textarea to grow , after clicking the send button ,the text area will be still at the same grown height although I empty it.

I tried to reset the height after clicking the button but that didn't help.

here is my code :

```js
TAgrow(document.querySelector('.js-grow'));
function TAgrow(container) {
    var area = container.querySelector('textarea');
    var clone = container.querySelector('span');
    area.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        clone.textContent = area.value;
    });
}


var messageForm = document.getElementsByClassName('message-form');
messageForm[0].addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var messageContent = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;

    postMessage(messageContent , function (res) {
        var d = document.querySelector('.js-grow');
        d.querySelector('textarea').value = '';
        d.querySelector('textarea').setAttribute('height', 'calc(100% - 0.5625rem - 0.375rem)'); //my try
        d.querySelector('span').value = '';
        d.querySelector('span').setAttribute('height', 'calc(100% - 0.5625rem - 0.375rem)');  //my try
    });
});
```

```css
.grow {
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width:83%; 
        min-height: 4.28125rem ; 
        border-radius: 0.5625rem; 
        position: relative; 
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color:  #d7d7d7;
        background-color:  #ffffff; 
        left: 0.90625rem; right: 0.875rem;
    }
    .grow textarea,
    .grow pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        font-family: Nunito;
        color:  #616161;
        font-size: 0.9375rem;/* Approximation due to font substitution */
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.25rem;/* Approximation due to font substitution */
        text-align: left;  
        width: calc(100% - 0.5625rem - 1.1875rem);
        height: calc(100% - 0.5625rem - 0.375rem);
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.5625rem 1.1875rem 0.375rem 0.5625rem;
    }
    .grow textarea {
        resize: none;
        border: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0;
        overflow: visible;
        font-family: Nunito;
        color:  #616161;
        font-size: 0.9375rem;/* Approximation due to font substitution */
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.25rem;/* Approximation due to font substitution */
        text-align: left;  
        resize: none;
        margin:0;
    }
```

```html
<form class="message-form" >
     <div class="grow js-grow">
       <pre><span></span><br></pre>
       <textarea></textarea>
      </div>

      <button  type="submit" >Send</button>
</form>
```

The lines next to the comment "//my try" in the javascript did not work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Even if an HTML attribute `height` existed, it would likely not care about `calc`. You should set the CSS property `height` instead.

Comment: @CBroe I tried to set it to " "  but that did not return the original design

Comment: @CBroe Also I tried to set it to "4.28125rem" but then the textarea wasn't able to grow again, instead a scrollbr appears.

Comment: Why would you need to _re-set_ the height of the textarea at all - where are you _setting_ it to something different than the value it gets from the stylesheet in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe the textarea grows when the message gets longer , and when I press send, the textarea gets empty and its height doesn't come back to the original one

Comment: Ah ok, I see, you are achieving that by cloning the text into the pre element. Your mistake is simply how you tried to clear the span again - span's don't have a `value`. You used `textContent` to set it - so use the same to remove it again as well. Apart from doing that, and clearing the text area, you should not have to do anything else, especially no CSS manipulation.

Comment: @CBroe How did I mess that??? I've been trying so long and nothing working ,,really thank you sooo much :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `height` attribute for html, you need to set the height by css, try having a class that has all the original styles of the text area, when the user interacts (click, change, input..whatever) with the textarea remove the class with the original styles and add the `.grow` class then when the user submits the form you can remove the `.grow` class and add the class back that had the original styles. This way, your event handlers are simply toggling back and forth between two different classes on the text area, one where your form is at its set original style and the other where it can be flexible and grow according to the user input.